# Spray-json and missing json writer that is defined

Tags: scala, spray-json

I'm new to Scala and maybe this issue is easy to solve but i'm struggling to understand why I have compilations errors.

So I have my case classes

```
case class AggregationQuery  (
  startDate: String,
  endDate: String,
  aggregates: Aggregates,
  value: Value,
  options: Options   
)

case class Aggregates (aggregate: List[String])
case class Options (excludePredicted: Boolean,excludeZeroMetricValue: Boolean)
case class Value (name: String,metric: String,parameters: Parameters)
case class Parameters (numberFormat: String,bigNumberFormat: String,currency: String)
```

for each I created extensions to RootJsonFormat

```
object OptionsProtocol {
  implicit object optionValue extends RootJsonFormat[Options] {
    def write(option: Options): JsValue = {
      JsObject(
        "excludePredicted" -> option.excludePredicted.toJson,
        "excludeZeroMetricValue" -> option.excludeZeroMetricValue.toJson
      )
    }
    override def read(json: JsValue): Options = ???
  }
}

object ValueProtocol {
  implicit object parametersValue extends  RootJsonFormat[Value] {
    def write(value: Value): JsValue = {
      JsObject(
        "metric" -> value.metric.toJson,
        "name" -> value.name.toJson,
        "paramters" -> value.parameters.toJson
      ).toJson
    }

    override def read(json: JsValue) = ???
  }
}

object AggregatesProtocol  {
  implicit object optionValue extends RootJsonFormat[Aggregates] {
    def write(aggregate: Aggregates): JsValue = {
      val list= aggregate.aggregate
      JsObject( "aggregates" ->list.toJson )
     }
    override def read(json: JsValue): Aggregates = ???
  }}
```

and then I added one more RootJsonFormat that I assume will aggregate the above formatters

```
object AggregateQueryProtocol  {
    implicit object  aggregateQueryValue extends  RootJsonFormat[AggregationQuery] {
      def write(query: AggregationQuery): JsValue = {
        JsObject(
          "startDate" -> query.startDate.toJson,
          "endDate" -> query.endDate.toJson,
         "aggregates" -> query.aggregates.toJson,
          "value" -> query.value.toJson,
          "options" -> query.options.toJson
        )
      }
      override def read(json: JsValue): AggregationQuery = ???
    }
}
```

And now I wanted to create my AggregationQuery json

```
AggregationQuery(
  dateRange.startDate,
  dateRange.endDate,
  filters,
  aggregates,
  value,
  option
).toJson;
```

But I have the compilation error for Aggregates and Options that there is no jsonwriter defined,

```
Error:(23, 43) not enough arguments for method toJson: (implicit writer: spray.json.JsonWriter[aggreagateQuery.Aggregates])spray.json.JsValue.
Unspecified value parameter writer.
         "aggregates" -> query.aggregates.toJson,
Error:(23, 43) Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for aggreagateQuery.Aggregates
         "aggregates" -> query.aggregates.toJson,
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, all imports are added. 
It's weird also because there is no error for Value class. Basically, these classes are very similar and placed in the same package:/

Maybe someone could give me some hint ?

Regards 
Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
import spray.json.{JsObject, JsValue, RootJsonFormat, _}

object Main extends App {

  case class AggregationQuery(startDate: String,
                           endDate: String,
                           aggregates: Aggregates,
                           value: Value,
                           options: Options)



case class Aggregates(aggregate: List[String])

  case class Options(excludePredicted: Boolean, excludeZeroMetricValue: Boolean)

  case class Parameters(numberFormat: String, bigNumberFormat: String, currency: String)

  case class Value(name: String, metric: String, parameters: Parameters)


  implicit object optionsFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Options] {
    def write(option: Options): JsValue = {


    JsObject(
        "excludePredicted" -> option.excludePredicted.toJson,
        "excludeZeroMetricValue" -> option.excludeZeroMetricValue.toJson
      )
    }

    override def read(json: JsValue): Options = Options(excludePredicted = true, excludeZeroMetricValue = false)
  }


  implicit object parametersFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Parameters] {
    def write(parameters: Parameters): JsValue = {
      JsObject(
        "numberFormat" -> parameters.numberFormat.toJson,
        "bigNumberFormat" -> parameters.bigNumberFormat.toJson,
        "currency" -> parameters.currency.toJson
      )
    }

    override def read(json: JsValue): Parameters = Parameters("", "", "")
  }


  implicit object valueFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Value] {
    def write(value: Value): JsValue = {
      JsObject(
        "metric" -> value.metric.toJson,
        "name" -> value.name.toJson,
        "paramters" -> value.parameters.toJson
      ).toJson
    }

    override def read(json: JsValue) = Value("", "", Parameters("", "", ""))
  }


  implicit object aggregatesValue extends RootJsonFormat[Aggregates] {
    def write(aggregate: Aggregates): JsValue = {
      val list = aggregate.aggregate
      JsObject("aggregates" -> list.toJson)
    }

    override def read(json: JsValue): Aggregates = Aggregates(List())
  }


  implicit object aggregateQueryValue extends RootJsonFormat[AggregationQuery] {
    def write(query: AggregationQuery): JsValue = {
      JsObject(
        "startDate" -> query.startDate.toJson,
        "endDate" -> query.endDate.toJson,
        "aggregates" -> query.aggregates.toJson,
        "value" -> query.value.toJson,
        "options" -> query.options.toJson
      )
    }

    override def read(json: JsValue): AggregationQuery =
      AggregationQuery("", "", Aggregates(List()), Value("", "", Parameters("", "", "")), Options(excludePredicted = true, excludeZeroMetricValue = false))
  }


  AggregationQuery("2016", "2018", Aggregates(List()), Value("", "", Parameters("", "", "")), Options(excludePredicted = true, excludeZeroMetricValue = false)).toJson

}
```

I basically added parametersFormat and removed the objects that were wrapped around you formatters.

Hope this helps.